# Disable Xdebugstack trace in apache error.log without disabling Xdebug

Tags: php, apache, xdebug

I recently installed xdebug, and now stack traces are printed to my apache error.log:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function get_upload() on null in /var/www/html/template/user/post-single.php on line 10
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/html/index.php:0
PHP   2. include() /var/www/html/index.php:19
```

I dont like them, as they clutter my log, and if i need them i will get them from my debugging client. Is there any way i can disable them?

**EDIT:** To be clear, i do not want to disable Xdebug, I just want it to not print the stack traces.

Comment: add `xdebug.profiler_enable = off` & `xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = off` to the bottom of your php.ini and restart your php service

Comment: @iam-decoder both are already off